# Mesh makes spikes while trying to smooth

Tags: mesh

I am pretty new to blender. I am trying to model a mask from a video game, and while I am trying to smooth the eye area, these “spikes” keep popping up. Im not sure what to do. I had made the mask from a UV sphere , booleaned out from a face model. Any help would be appreaciated. I've tried shading smooth, solidify modifier, and nothing has seemed to work.
This is the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HaHhav8OdKQ6mFUZqk-QrsdmxBG-qKhI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Go into edit mode and, on vertex select mode and with nothing selected, click on Select->Select All By trait->Non Manifold. Then press Ctrl+X to dissolve them.
Some vertices become separated. So select a vertex in the mask and press Ctrl+L and Ctrl+I to select them. Then delete them with X->Vetices.
Then you should probably remesh the thing with a modifier or the sculpt tool

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get artefacts with smoothing is that you "Booleaned" two objects of different mesh density. The front of your mask is too dense and the back of the mask is low poly. The spikes caused by smoothing will be exactly at the border between the two densities.

What you can do is **remesh** the mask to desirable density using the **Remesh Modifier** or in Sculpt mode enable Dyntopo with **Detailing = Constant Detail** and **Resolution ~= 130**, then click **Detail Flood Fill** button.

**Note:** *Enabling Wireframe overlay on your object will give you an idea about the mesh density in both cases.*

Once you are happy with the result from the remeshing you can apply a Smooth Modifier or smooth out the surface via sculpting.